# MVC _Layout with Action using Session -order of loading is an issue for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

All,

I have an MVC _Layout.cshtml that calls:

```
@Html.Action("GetActionStrip", "Vehicles")
```

I also have a Controller that loads some views.

My Issue is that I have a controller action called **GetVehicleDetails** which gets a vehicle by ID.

The Action on:

```
@Html.Action("GetActionStrip", "Vehicles")
```

requires that GetVehicleDetails loads first as it need to put a vehicle id into session.

This is not working as:

```
@Html.Action("GetActionStrip", "Vehicles")
```

Loads before GetVehicleDetails.

```
@Html.Action("GetActionStrip", "Vehicles")
```

Needs to be on multiple views, that's why I put it in the _Layout file.

I can get it to work by putting:

```
@Html.Action("GetActionStrip", "Vehicles")
```

On every view I need it on and then they load in the correct order. ie.. the controller action GetVehicleDetails sets the vehicle id into session and then:

```
@Html.Action("GetActionStrip", "Vehicles")
```

Reads the session value.

Has anyone got any idea if I can do it the way I want or will I have to put my @Html.Action on every view which kind of breaks the DRY principle.

thanks
RuSs

**Paul, I tried to write you a comment but the character limit killed me. Here is my comment:**

Paul,

Thanks for the message. I understand what you have written but before I continue and try to implement something like this I just want to be sure you understand, fully, the scenario.

Will YOUR scenario cater for the fact that the code that needs the session value is called from an @Html.Action in my **_Layout** (master page so to speak) whereas I need my controller get action to receive a parameter and set this parameter into session.

From what I understand, _Layouts (master pages) load first so my @Html.Action would run and look for the session value. But, as this code is in a _Layout, it would run first and hence the GET on my controller has not yet set the session from the actions passed in parameter.

Note: my _Layout doesnt have it's own controller (not sure if this matters)

Thanks
RuSs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something about the design is fundamentally incorrect. You shouldn't have different components being tightly coupled like this. The order shouldn't matter for which one comes first.

Here is how I might do what you're looking for. I'd create a model bound class that you can receive in your controller actions where you need the session value. The model will pull the session value from the database or wherever if it hasn't been set yet otherwise it uses the session value. Now order doesn't matter. Better yet you could make MySessionObject an interface and then you can mock it out in your test cases.

```
    public interface IMySessionObject
    {
        int GetValueX();
    }

    public class MySessionObject : IModelBinder, IMySessionObject
    {
        private HttpContextBase _httpContext;
        private MySessionObject(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContext;
        }

        public int GetValueX()
        {
            if (_httpContext.Session["x"] == null)
            {
                _httpContext.Session["x"] = 54; // Get the value here.
            }
            return (int)_httpContext.Session["x"];
        }

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var context = controllerContext.HttpContext;
            var obj = new MySessionObject(context);
            return obj;
        }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(IMySessionObject obj)
        {
            ViewBag.X = obj.GetValueX();

            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About(IMySessionObject obj)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact(IMySessionObject obj)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Paul, I added a comment for you in the actual body of my question as there were not enough allowable characters to explain my self properly

Comment: Also, what did you mean by this: **Something about the design is fundamentally incorrect. You shouldn't have different components being tightly coupled like this**

Comment: Basically you shouldn't require components be be coupled in a way that order of loading matters. It would make it really hard for someone later to track down why it is breaking if they changed the order. The solution above solves this so that whatever loads first is safe.

Comment: But I require that the session is set 1st in my action so the order definitely matter. If my query string param passes in VehicleId=3 it must be set by my action on my controller that receives it before my other code that is called from my _Layout reads session. I might be missing the point but if order is important then I need to ensure the order is correct. Sorry to be a pain!!

Comment: I found the issue. I didn't mention I was using Sitecore as I didnt think it was realted to the issue. Sitecore forces the _Layout to load first where as in a standard MVC project the order is the other way around. Very annoying and sorry for wasting your time. You must have wondered what drugs I was on!!

Comment: Paul, I may vote your answer later but I feel your answer is not totally clear yet. My comment: But I require that the session is set 1st in my action so the order definitely matter. If my query string param passes in VehicleId=3 it must be set by my action on my controller that receives it before my other code that is called from my _Layout reads session. I might be missing the point but if order is important then I need to ensure the order is correct.

Comment: With a model binder like I've shown you can grab the query string values off of the request object. I'd suggest looking up more info on custom ModelBinders in ASP.NET MVC and look at all the things you have access to bind to. They are very useful when the object you want to receive as a parameter to an action method will be an object with more binding logic than just a one to one mapping of params to properties.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul. I think your answer is correct without Sitecore CMS being part if the scenario. Ill vote you up but still doesn't fix my issue. Here is my other post which explains it better. 
I don't expect you use Sitecore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867915/order-of-loading-layout-and-url-driven-action-is-opposite-to-a-standard-non-sit  ill try to find a way for Sitecore NOT to declaratively load my _layout before my MVC code runs.